# update elements of array dart

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I have this array using dart language .

```
  var array1 = ["1111" , "2222" ,"3333"];
```

if user click button I need to update array for example ;
I want array to be like

```
array1 =  ["4444" , "1111" ,"2222"];
```

and if user click again

```
array1 =  ["5555" , "4444" ,"1111"];
```

I hope you understand what I mean . I don't know how can I do that

button code :

```
 child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if(!_ischecked){
                updateArray();
                }else{
                  //
                }
              },

Future<void> updateArray() async {
    setState(() {
      _ischecked = true;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Where is your button?

Comment: I want to know the idea . button is not important.  I need to know how to do with array elements

Comment: You do it the same way you update any other variable. Honestly, at least give us an example of you attempting to use a button to modify a variable, which shows you know what you are talking about.

Comment: ok . I update the post

Comment: Then in `setState`, just set the index of the list element that you want to modify, for example array1[1] = '114514' or array1 = array1.sublist(0, array1.length - 1); array1.insert(0, '1919810') (which removes the last element and insert a new element at the beginning). All kinds of array manipulation you can put it here.

Comment: ``array1.insert(0, "444");`` and ``array1.removeAt(3);`` should do !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to add an element to the start of the list, and remove the last, you could do it as follows:

```
List<String> updateArray(List<String> array, String addToStartOfArray) {
  return array
    ..insert(0, addToStartOfArray)
    ..removeLast();
}
```

This method first add the string addToStartOfArray to the beginning of the list, and then removes the last element of the List.

You can use this method as follows:

```
void main() {
  var array = ["1111", "2222", "3333"];
  array = updateArray(array, "4444");
  print(array);
  array = updateArray(array, "5555");
  print(array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your want to update the first index of your `List` with value incremented by `1111` to the previous highest value of the `List`. If this is not the algorithm, just check out the logic behind List manipulation.

```dart
// To find max in the List
import 'dart:math';

  var list1 = ["1111", "2222", "3333"];

  void updateList() {
    // Create new List<int> out the List<String> to easily find max & do the addition
    List<int> intList = list1.map(int.parse).toList();

    // The current max in the List
    int currentMax = intList.fold(0, max);

    // The new max in String
    String newMax = (currentMax + 1111).toString();

    // Add the new max at the beginning of your List
    list1.insert(0, newMax);

    // Remove the last item so the List can have only three items
    list1.removeAt(3);

    print(list1);
    setState(() {});
  }
```

After 6 clicks prints :

```
[4444, 1111, 2222]
[5555, 4444, 1111]
[6666, 5555, 4444]
[7777, 6666, 5555]
[8888, 7777, 6666]
[9999, 8888, 7777]
```